# Is Windows disk mirroring more likely to lead to unbootable system than hardware RAID1?

Tags: hardware-raid, mirroring

Our server provider has suggested that we use NVMe drives with Windows disk mirroring for our new servers, instead of SATA drives that are connected to Adaptec hardware RAID controller and configured as RAID1. We are concerned whether the disk mirroring solution is more likely to result in a system that cannot be booted, compared to the hardware RAID solution.

Comment: hardware raid should be preferred due to performance, and the point of the question is not very clear

Comment: It is possible to have a system that will not start from the second disk, yes. You should test the procedure that you use when you set it up. The second disk can be prepared by copying the startup partition to the second drive. A sample procedure for GPT disks is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/establish-boot-to-gpt-mirrors

Comment: @djdomi - we recently detected a failing SSD on an Adaptec 8405e RAID1 array which was compounded by the raid controller proceeding to rebuild a good disk from a bad disk ( after a system reboot ) resulting in total storage array failure. i don't know why the raid controller did this but i would like to know if switching to software raid increases or reduces the chance of this event occurring again. performancewise, the two systems are similar when performing mysql restore.

Comment: It's important to have more than just two disks in an important server, because the risk of failure increases during the rebuilding process. I would suggest having at least 4-6 drives and using RAID 10 or 5/6 depending on the specific use case. It's best to avoid using a Windows software RAID due to the impact on performance. Ultimately, it doesn't matter what kind of RAID is used in case of a failure. NVMe is of course faster as Ata/sata

Comment: From the bootability standpoint, *if you documented and tested the procedure*, these are equal. I don't get why everybody out there thinks HW RAID is a silver bullet. It is not more reliable than SW RAID at all, I'd say. I've worked a lot with both of them. Even "foolproofness" is not necessarily better in the HW RAID, which you've seem to already learned that hard way.

Comment: Don't use RAID5/6 anymore these days. It's not state of the art, it takes forever to rebuild harddisks in a RAID5/6 and has a strong tendency to kill the remaining drives due overload. Always use RAID1, (You can even use more than 2 drives) it's more simple and more robust. I don't know about Windows software RAID, but in the Linux world, software RAID is better than hardware RAID in many terms. See inbuilt RAID function of BTRFS and ZFS filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with hardware RAID as stability-wise it’s preferred over Windows software RAID implementation. Watch out for dedicated RAID boot cards like f.e. Dell BOSS, they exist for a good reason.

Comment: With basic large file copy testing, the hardware RAID solution using SATA SSDs writes at roughly 500MB/s. The software RAID solution using NVMe SSDs writes at roughly 2500MB/s. From a performance perspective, there is a compelling reason to go NVMe. Having said that, MySQL DB restores seem to take the same time on both platforms.

Comment: Hardware RAID + NVMe is not an option offered by the server supplier. It's either HW RAID + SATA, or SVR2019 Mirroring + NVMe.